# child app as npm package does not rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a parent app that loads a child app created as a separate npm package. When the child app (`MyComponent`) state changes, the parent app doesn't rerender, causing some "rerender-blocking" for the child app.

```
// parent app
// package.json
"my-child-app": "^0.1.0"

// ChildApp.jsx
import ChildApp from "my-child-app";
...
render() {
  return <ChildApp appHistory={history} />;
}

// child app
render() {
  const { history } = createHistory(this.props.appHistory);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="*" component={MyComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Is the issue due to the routes? Or something else?

Comment: Why should the parent component re-render if the state of the child component is changed?

Comment: @FortyTwo the issue is that the parent doesn't rerender when the child state changes and it blocks the child from rerendering. So maybe the parent doesn't need to rerender, but then I'm not sure why the child isn't rerendering. ChildApp runs great by itself, but when it's imported inside the Parent, the ChildApp doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like if you have this sort of unpredictability that you need a function passed from the parent to the child component and when that child changes you should call that parent function to forceUpdate or just set the state again and it will rerender.

```
this.forceUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It turns out the webpack config in the parent app had:

```
{
  ...
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      poll: false
    }
  }
}
```